# Cypher find paths query

Tags: path, neo4j, cypher

Don't have much experience in `Cypher` paths queries, but it seems that paths are the rational way to do what I want efficiently...

I have the following relevant relationships in my `Neo4j`:

```
p1-[r:SNEAK]->otherProfile
p1-[r:FRIEND]-otherProfile (the direction not relevant) 
p1-[r:HANG]->venue<-[r:HANG]-otherProfile
p1-[r:INTERACT]->session<-[r:INTERACT]-otherProfile
p1-[r:INTERACT]->session<-[r:LIKE]-otherProfile
```

Let's say I have **p1** in my hand, I want to perform a query to retrieve all the profiles where at least one condition from the following is exist (with **distinct** on the profiles):

- *p1 sneak at them*
- *p1 is a (friend) || (friend of friend)*
- *p1 hang at least one venue as them*
- *p1 has a session with them*
- *p1 has a session and they liked it*

I also need the ability to extract the relation types in order to figure out what is the relation 
between these profiles...

- lets assume that these are all the relation types in the DB

At first it seems simple just retrieve all the below paths:

```
p=p1-[r*1..2]-profile
```

Few problems with that :

1) It will returns also profiles which sneaked at **p1** 
2) It will returns also profiles which one of **p1** friends sneaked at them
3) It will returns also profiles which are friends of profiles **p1** sneaked on them

Is it possible to perform one `Cypher` query which will do the job for my use-case?

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using? If I read your question correctly, you want to perform a query for general relationships, except for any that are connected by the `SNEAK` relationship?

Comment: I am using 1.8...Actually it is not correct, looking also for SNEAK but in specific direction ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Easy shortcut is the ability to do path qualifiers in the `WHERE` clause using not. So you can do your match, and then specify `WHERE NOT(p1-[:SNEAK*1..2]->profile)` or however you want to qualify it.